JS Canvas API incorrectly rendering font
I have imported in my project the Neue-Plak semibold font:

I use the context API and try rendering the text with:
  const width = 1456
  const height = 816
  const canvas = createCanvas(width, height)
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d')

  registerFont(plakSemiBoldPath, { family: 'NeuePlak-SemiBold' })
  context.fillStyle = '#FFF'
  context.font = '80px NeuePlak-SemiBold'
  context.fillText("367.34x", 100, 525)

Then I overlay the rendered text to a template with sharp:
  sharp(templatePath)
  .composite([{ input: textBuffer, blend: 'over' }])
  .toFile('./image_output/test.png', (err, info) => {
    if (err) reject("Error generating image " + err)
    resolve(true)
  })

The problem is that the output renders the ultra-light version of the text, despite me providing the semibold font:

I tried several things:

Converting the font to other formats.
Downloading the font from other sources.
Tinkering with font-weight parameters in context.font()

Nothing worked.
I also am quite sure the font isn't variable, as it provides you with several style files upon download:


Try { family: 'NeuePlak-SemiBold', weight: 'bold' } in your registerFont options, and context.font = 'bold 80px NeuePlak-SemiBold'.

Doesn't work unfortunately @CBroe

Or try the font string bold 80px NeuePlak-SemiBold? If the font file is correct, then it shouldn't just decide to render a different font, that wouldn't make sense. It's probably somewhat variable tbh, so try to specify the font size when telling canvas to draw. Also, you mention no library that would provide the registerFont capability, which could be relevant.

canvas provides the registerFont capability. Also I thought of the variable font possibility, but it indeed isn't. I used a tool that detects variable fonts and it came back as a static font.

I managed to fix the issue by using FontForge to extract the characters I was interested in and pasting them into a new font. Then to export it simply do File -> Generate Fonts and click on generate.

I had to play a bit with the generation options to get it to work. These are the ones I've used (don't know if all are necessary, got it through trial and error)

You might get the following problem when generating the font: 'Non-integral coordinates'. Fix by selecting all characters, go to Element -> Round -> To Int
I do not know why this works and what the problem with the original font was to be honest. Perhaps a font expert might help!
